# Compiling shared and static libraries into a shared library using the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries, libcurl

I have come across a problem with trying to compile cURL with SSL support into an app.

So far, I have successfully compiled the openSSL package into libcrypt.so and libssl.so.

I believe I have successfully compiled a version of libcurl.a with SSL support using the configure script and running it through the cross-chain compiler found in the NDK (under a linux environment).

Now, I am attempting to write a .so library under Eclipse that can be called by the Java code of an Android App.

Here is the file structure so far:

```
Project Folder ---> jni ---> include ---> curl ---> curl headers
                         |            |
                         |             -> openssl ---> ssl and crypto headers
                         |
                          -> libcrypto.so
                          -> libssl.so
                          -> libcurl.a
                          -> jniProcessRequest.c
                          -> Android.mk
```

Android.mk reads:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE := crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcrypto.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/openssl/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libssl.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/openssl/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := curl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcurl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/curl/
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := JNIProcessRequest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JNIProcessRequest.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := crypto ssl
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := curl
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

jniProcessRequest.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "include/curl/curl.h"
#include <android/log.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_jniprocessrequest_MainActivity_jniProcessRequest(JNIEnv * env, jobject obje){
CURL *conn;
conn = curl_easy_init();
}
```

Every time I attempt to compile the above, I have undefined reference errors in Eclipse:

```
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libJNIProcessRequest.so] Error 1
undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'
```

I am thinking this is some sort of linkage error but am struggling to find where the error is occurring. I have spent nearly two days trying all different methods of placing the shared libraries in differing places, switching the static libcurl with a shared libcurl, altering the Android.mk file and following tutorials on how to get cURL working in Android.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't find any documentation to confirm this, but I've always seen the `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` point to the path of a *folder*, and not individual files. It's probably worth trying `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := include/curl`

Comment: Hi mbrenon, I have made the suggested change and updated my code above, but I still seem to be getting the same two errors at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem was stemming from an incorrectly built libcurl.a static library. I replaced my library with one that was compiled by a user on GitHub and without changing any code, the linkage errors disappeared.

Comment: Hi @Jake, would you mind sharing the project folder (without your apps source code) containing the libcurl and all the other libraries to support curl with an android app? Basically just the jni folder would work... since I am having troubles compiling libcurl on my environment

Comment: Hi @Thiago, I don't currently have access the project folder but I believe the libcurl.so library I used was from either [link](https://github.com/liudongmiao/curl-android) or [link](https://github.com/fuhu/curl-android).

Comment: Hi @Jake, Thanks for getting back to me. I will take a look at the links you shared as the libcurl.a I am using might not have ssl support as it keeps returning me unsupported protocol error.

Answer (score 0):

You use `curl` as a prebuilt module.

As stated by the NDK documentation you should take care to wrap it under `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` and (most importantly) `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)` directives as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Right after take care to wrap your `JNIProcessRequest` module with `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` and `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`.

*For more details please refer to the `docs/PREBUILTS.html` section that you can find within your Android NDK folder (it looks like [this](http://www.srombauts.fr/android-ndk-r5b/docs/PREBUILTS.html)).*

Comment: Hi deltheil, I have implemented the changes you recommended and updated my code in the original post to reflect the new changes. I also read through the documentation you recommended. Now my errors appear to have changed to some form of linkage errors, any ideas?